# Can I combine two lists into one list if they don't have the same number of parameters?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

```
classA a = new classA (int width, int height);
classB b = new classB(in far, int near, String time);
List<classA> listA = new ArrayList<>();
listA.add(a);
List<classB> listB = new ArrayList<>();
listB.add(b);
List<Base> combinedList = new ArrayList<>();
combinedList.addAll(listA);
combinedList.addAll(ListB);
```

Is dding these two lists in this example is possible?
classA and classB both extends classBase.

Comment: Do classA and classB extend or implement Base?

Comment: classA and classB both extends  classBase. classA extends Base and classB extends Base

Comment: Then it should work. Have you tried doing it? Is there an error you get or an unexpected result?

Comment: Works but not properly. I'll try some more. If I couldn't fix it. I'll comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look:

`Base.java`:

```
public class Base {
}
```

`ClassA.java`:

```
public class ClassA extends Base {
    int age;
    String race;
    String country;

    public ClassA(int age, String race, String country) {
        this.age = age;
        this.race = race;
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassA -> age: " + age + ", race: " + race + ", country :" + country;
    }
}
```

`ClassB.java`:

```
public class ClassB extends Base {
    String day;
    String month;
    String year;

    public ClassB(String day, String month, String year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassB -> day: " + day + ", month: " + month + ", year :" + year;
    }
}
```

`main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ClassA ArrayList
        ArrayList<ClassA> classAArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // ClassB ArrayList
        ArrayList<ClassB> classBArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Base ArrayList
        ArrayList<Base> baseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // ClassA items
        ClassA itemA_1 = new ClassA(1, "val_race_1", "val_country_1");
        ClassA itemA_2 = new ClassA(2, "val_race_2", "val_country_2");
        ClassA itemA_3 = new ClassA(3, "val_race_3", "val_country_3");

        classAArrayList.add(itemA_1);
        classAArrayList.add(itemA_2);

        // ClassB items
        ClassB itemB_1 = new ClassB("day_1", "month_1", "year_1");
        ClassB itemB_2 = new ClassB("day_2", "month_2", "year_2");
        ClassB itemB_3 = new ClassB("day_3", "month_3", "year_3");

        classBArrayList.add(itemB_1);
        classBArrayList.add(itemB_2);

        // Base ArrayList can have the ClassA ArrayList or ClassB ArrayList
        baseArrayList.addAll(classAArrayList);
        baseArrayList.addAll(classBArrayList);

        // Base ArrayList can have the ClassA item or ClassB item
        baseArrayList.add(itemA_3);
        baseArrayList.add(itemB_3);

        for (Base base : baseArrayList) {
            System.out.println("item -> " + base.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I figured it out and yes it is possible.